# Do I have any method to override System Properties in Java?

Tags: java, casting, jvm, runtime

I am getting a practical issue and the issue can be dascribed as follows.

We are developing a component (Say a plugin) to do some task when an event is triggered within an external CMS using the API provided by them. They have provided some jar libraries, So what we are doing is implementing an Interface provided by them. Then an internal method is called when an event is triggered. (The CMS is creating only one instance of class when the first event triggers, then it just executes the method with each event trigger)

The function can be summarized as follows,

```
import com.external.ProvidedInterface;


public class MonitorProgram implements ProvidedInterface{

   public void process(){
      //This method is called when an event is triggered in CMS
   }

}
```

Within our class we are using "javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection" (JAVA 1.5). But HttpsURLConnection migrated to javax.net.ssl from com.sun.net.ssl for 1.4. But it seems the CMS I am referring to (We dont know their implementation actually) uses something like this

```
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs","com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
```

leading to a ClassCastException in our code.

I think my question is clear. In our case we cant set VM parameters,

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=
```

Also we cant set it back using,

```
System.setProperty("")
```

because the VM instance is same for CMS and our program.

What can I do for get this problem resolved? And idea or experiences?

Comment: Why can't you use System.setProperty and -Djava.protocol.handler/pkgs ? It's not very clear in your question...

Comment: If I used System.setProperty then the properties will be set to VM causing the CMS (External party) to malfunction. And we are just keeping the above class within the CMS installation. We are not going to manually execute it. The CMS automatically creates an instance So we have no way to set VM parameters

Comment: To clear it up: You call something in the CMS which returns "HttpsURLConnection". But instead of a javax.net.*, the CMS tries to create something from com.sun.net.ssl.*. If you force the CMS to use javax.net.*, then it will throw a ClassCastException somewhere deep in the CMS' code. If you don't, then you have a ClassCastException in your code. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not clear for me.

Do you want to overwrite a system property?
You can do this.

Overwrite the System.property before calling the external library method and when the method returns you can set the old System.property back

```
    final String propertyName = "Property";
    String oldProperty = System.getProperty(propertyName);
    System.setProperty(propertyName,"NEW_VALUE");
    monitorProgram.process();
    System.setProperty(propertyName,oldProperty);
```

Or do you want to prevent, that the called process overwrites the system.property?
And why you can not set the system property by hand?

Comment: Hi, I added a comment above with explanation to original post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are going to have much success getting two pieces of code to use different properties.

In your own code however, you can define your own URLStreamHandlerFactory.  Doing this will allow you to create a javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection from a URL.  While protocol handlers aren't the easiest thing to figure out, I think you can get them to do the job.

See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the offending class in the stack trace
2. Use [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) or a similar tool to decompile it.
3. Fix the name of the property
4. Compile the resulting file and either replace the .class file in the CMS's jar or put it into a place which is earlier in the classpath.
5. Use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) to automate this process (well, the compile and build of the JAR; not the decompiling)
6. When it works, make sure you save everything (original file, changed file, build file) somewhere so you can easily do it again.

While this may sound like a ridiculous or dangerous way to fix the issue, it will work. Especially since your CMS provider doesn't seem to develop his product actively.

Comment: We are not authorized to make changes to the CMS provided archives. Even we are not releasing them. It is customers responsibility to obtain those Jar files

Comment: How about filing a bug report asking them to fix this?